# XGrabButton doesn't capture clicks when another button is held down

Tags: c, xlib

I have some code that uses XGrabButton to capture mouse clicks. I want it to always capture all clicks on the specified buttons, regardless of any other concerns. It currently uses the following invocation:

```
XSelectInput(display, window, ButtonPressMask);
XGrabButton(display, Button2, AnyModifier, window, True,
    ButtonPressMask, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None);
XGrabButton(display, Button3, AnyModifier, window, True,
    ButtonPressMask, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None);
XGrabButton(display, Button4, AnyModifier, window, True,
    ButtonPressMask, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None);
```

However, pressing and holding button 1 (the left mouse button, which is not captured by my code) causes clicks on the other buttons to not be captured. How do I prevent this from happening?

**Edit for clarification:**

- I want to capture buttons 2-4 always, and button 1 never.
- The above invocation captures buttons 2-4 just fine normally.
- It does **NOT** capture button 1 (left click).
- It will **NOT** capture buttons 2-4 while button 1 is held down.

How do I make it capture buttons 2-4 while button 1 is held down?

Comment: Run `xev` from the command line.  Does it capture buttons 2-4 while button 1 is held down?  This might be an issue with your mouse or X configuration, rather than a problem with your program.

Comment: Yes, it does capture buttons 2-4 while button 1 is held down. Or it reports them in the console at least.

Comment: Actually, for that matter, if I modify my program to make it capture button 1, then the other buttons are captured properly while button 1 is held down. The issue only seems to happen if the held-down button is **NOT** captured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope there is more to the code if it acts as you say:

> "*However, pressing and holding button 1 (the left mouse button, **which is not captured by my code**) causes clicks on the other buttons to not be captured.*"

The line:

```
XSelectInput(display, window, ButtonPressMask);
```

will cause all buttons to be captured. The additional `XGrabButton` calls are (*redundant?*) as you do not specify any parameters that differ from the default ones.

However; if it in fact is how you say, that even with that code `Button1` is not captured, or you have some other code where i.e. `XSelectInput` is not called - I'll take that as base to start with.

---

#### Event distribution

Every window has a event queue. An event is ***sent*** to a window when it is generated in that window. But, the window only ***receives*** the event if it has selected it or it is always selected. *Or as a side effect to an Xlib routine*. Only when it ***receives*** the event it is placed in the queue.

If we use `XSelectInput()` and select most masks, */usr/include/X11/X.h EVENT DEFINITIONS*, and use `XNextEvent()` to have a look we'll typically see something like this:

```
 ...
 19: Event EnterNotify     # Window Entry/Exit Events
 20: Event KeymapNotify    # X send after every EnterNotify and FocusIn event
 21: Event MotionNotify    # Keyboard and Pointer Events
 22: Event ButtonPress   2 # Button 2 down
 23: Event ButtonRelease 2 # Button 2 up
 24: Event ButtonPress   1 # Button 1 down
 25: Event ButtonPress   2 # Button 1 and 2 down
 ...
```

---

***If*** we remove *ButtonPressMask* and *ButtonReleaseMask* from `XSelectInput` and use `XGrabButton()` to grab events for every button except `1` and run the program again the events is mapping a tendency:

```
 22: Event LeaveNotify       # Button 1 pressed causes "blurring" of window.
 23: Event EnterNotify       # Button 1 released
 24: Event KeymapNotify
 25: Event ButtonPress   3   # Button 3 down
 26: Event ButtonPress   1   # Button 3 + 1 down; 1 registers as Press 
                             #                    even if not tracked.
 27: Event ButtonRelease 3   # Button 3 up
 28: Event MotionNotify
 29: Event ButtonRelease 1   # Button 1 up
 30: Event LeaveNotify       # Button 1 pressed, 1+2 pressed, 1+2+3 …
 31: Event EnterNotify       # Button 1 released, 2 released, …
 32: Event KeymapNotify
 33: Event ButtonPress   2
 34: Event ButtonPress   3
 35: Event ButtonPress   1
 36: Event ButtonRelease 2
 37: Event ButtonRelease 3
```

We observe that the button events, when pressing multiple, inherits status of first. You can also see this with `ltrace`, `strace`, `xev` etc. I.e. *xev* registers buttons that are *not* captured internally. As mentioned earlier; events are *sent* to the window, but only registered are *received*. That is with exception of some side effects as one for example can see when:

- *first* button pressed **is** set to capture; and then one that is **not** - the one that is not will also be queued in the event list.
- *first* button pressed is **not** set to capture; and then one that **is** - then neither is queued.

A button press on one that is not set to capture results in *LeaveNotify*, (*window is left*) - and parallel events are blocked.

---

#### How to solve

There are so many things to take into account here. All depending on the logic of the rest of the code project etc. There are however some basics. The simplest being to capture all buttons and flag and track; [XNextEvent](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/manipulating-event-queue/XNextEvent.html).

```
static const char *event_names[] = {
    "", "", "KeyPress", "KeyRelease", "ButtonPress", "ButtonRelease",
    "MotionNotify", "EnterNotify", "LeaveNotify", "FocusIn", "FocusOut",
    "KeymapNotify", "Expose", "GraphicsExpose", "NoExpose", "VisibilityNotify",
    "CreateNotify", "DestroyNotify", "UnmapNotify", "MapNotify", "MapRequest",
    "ReparentNotify", "ConfigureNotify", "ConfigureRequest", "GravityNotify",
    "ResizeRequest", "CirculateNotify", "CirculateRequest", "PropertyNotify",
    "SelectionClear", "SelectionRequest", "SelectionNotify", "ColormapNotify",
    "ClientMessage", "MappingNotify"
};

/* ... */

Display *dpy;
XEvent  ev;
int k = 0;

/* ... */

for (;;) {
    XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
    if ((ev.type == ButtonPress || ev.type == ButtonRelease) &&
                            ev.xbutton.button == Button1) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "%04d: BLOCK!     %-18s %d\n",
                k++, event_names[ev.type],
                ev.xbutton.button);
        continue;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%04d: PASS! Work %-18s", k++, event_names[ev.type]);
    switch (ev.type) {
        case ButtonPress:
        case ButtonRelease:
            fprintf(stderr, " %d", ev.xbutton.button);
            break;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Resulting in something like:

```
0005: PASS! Work FocusIn           
0006: BLOCK!     ButtonPress        1
0007: BLOCK!     ButtonRelease      1
0008: BLOCK!     ButtonPress        1
0009: BLOCK!     ButtonRelease      1
0010: BLOCK!     ButtonPress        1
0011: PASS! Work ButtonPress        3 # Button 1 is also down
0012: PASS! Work ButtonRelease      3
0013: BLOCK!     ButtonRelease      1
0014: PASS! Work ButtonPress        3
0015: PASS! Work ButtonRelease      3
0016: BLOCK!     ButtonPress        1
0017: PASS! Work ButtonPress        3
0018: PASS! Work ButtonRelease      3
0019: BLOCK!     ButtonRelease      1
0020: PASS! Work ButtonPress        2
0021: PASS! Work ButtonPress        3
0022: BLOCK!     ButtonPress        1
0023: BLOCK!     ButtonRelease      1
0024: PASS! Work ButtonRelease      2
0025: PASS! Work ButtonRelease      3
0026: BLOCK!     ButtonPress        1
0027: PASS! Work ButtonPress        3
0028: PASS! Work ButtonRelease      3
0029: PASS! Work ButtonPress        2
0030: PASS! Work ButtonRelease      2
0031: BLOCK!     ButtonRelease      1
0032: PASS! Work FocusOut
```

Another way could be to use [XIfEvent](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/manipulating-event-queue/XIfEvent.html), `XCheckIfEvent()`etc. It all depends on structure. One thing to remember / check is that some of the functions; i.e. `XIfEvent` does ***not*** remove the event from queue if it is ***not*** a match! So if you implement a `predicate` function that return `False` if event is i.e. *Button1Press* - that event will remain in queue.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm going to have to fiddle with it some more, by the looks of things, but you've given me some useful leads to follow.

Comment: @RyanArcher: Ups. I forgot to add `|| ev.type == ButtonRelease` in the code sample I pasted here. Corrected. Really, really sorry about that. Hopefully it did not lead to any confusion.

Comment: No problem. I've actually been working on a different project for the past few days and haven't really started re-working this thing yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works but you could force not to grab the button1 in your code by:

```
XUngrabButton(display, Button1, AnyModifier, window);
```

Comment: This is not what I asked. Edited question for clarification.